# SQL Server : how to display the accountid that are only on one set but not others

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

SQL Server 2008: I need to dispaly the unique accountid that are on only one set but not others.

For example: I need to display accountid with medications (warfarin, enoxaparin, rivaroxaban etc) with documenttype only of dmr. Accountid having document type hml,adm and dmr should not be displayed. or account with multiple document type should be avoided. Below is my code and results:

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    a.AccountID as AccountID,
    b.Visit_OID,
    b.DocumentType,
    c.GenericName,
    c.DocumentStatus,
    b.CollectedDTime
FROM 
    dbo.PatientVisit a
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.XMLDocStorage b ON a.Visit_oid = b.Visit_OID
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.MedList c ON b.storageoid = c.storageoid
WHERE 
    (c.GenericName  LIKE '%warfarin%'
     OR c.GenericName  LIKE '%enoxaparin%'
     OR c.GenericName  LIKE '%rivaroxaban%'
     OR c.GenericName  LIKE '%apixaban%'
     OR c.GenericName  LIKE '%dabigatran etexilate%'
     OR c.GenericName  LIKE '%edoxaban%')
    AND b.collectedDTime BETWEEN '20161001 00:00:00' AND '20161010  00:00:00'
    AND c.DocumentStatus ='Complete'
```

Result:

```
AccountID   Visit_OID   DocumentType    GenericName DocumentStatus  CollectedDTime
1011        101         ADM     rivaroxaban Complete    10/3/16 15:14
1011        101         HML     rivaroxaban Complete    10/3/16 12:48
1011        101         DMR     rivaroxaban Complete    10/3/16 10:17
1012        102         DMR     apixaban    Complete    10/4/16 10:48
1012        102         HML     apixaban    Complete    10/3/16 19:21
1013        103         DMR     warfarin    Complete    10/5/16 12:45
1014        104         HML     warfarin    Complete    10/4/16 15:25
1015        105         DMR     warfarin    Complete    10/6/16 12:57
```

Desired result:

```
AccountID   Visit_OID   DocumentType    GenericName DocumentStatus  CollectedDTime
1013        103         DMR     warfarin    Complete    10/5/16 12:45
1015        105         DMR     warfarin    Complete    10/6/16 12:57
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data for us to work with?  It's hard to rewrite this query when you cannot test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    v.AccountID AS AccountID,
    x.Visit_OID,
    x.DocumentType,
    m.GenericName,
    m.DocumentStatus,
    x.CollectedDTime
FROM 
    PatientVisit v INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT
        Visit_OID,
        collectedDTime,
        DocumentType
    FROM
        XMLDocStorage x LEFT OUTER JOIN
        (SELECT
            Visit_OID
        FROM
            XMLDocStorage
        WHERE
            collectedDTime >= '20161001 00:00:00' AND 
            collectedDTime < '20161011  00:00:00' AND
            DocumentType <> 'dmr'
        GROUP BY 
            Visit_OID       )  d ON
        x.visit_oid = d.visit_oid
    WHERE
        collectedDTime >= '20161001 00:00:00' AND 
        collectedDTime < '20161011  00:00:00'   AND
        d.visit_oid IS NULL ) x ON 
    v.Visit_oid = x.Visit_OID INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT
        storageoid,
        GenericName,
        DocumentStatus
    FROM
        MedList 
    WHERE
        (m.GenericName  LIKE '%warfarin%'
         OR m.GenericName  LIKE '%enoxaparin%'
         OR m.GenericName  LIKE '%rivaroxaban%'
         OR m.GenericName  LIKE '%apixaban%'
         OR m.GenericName  LIKE '%dabigatran etexilate%'
         OR m.GenericName  LIKE '%edoxaban%') 
        AND m.DocumentStatus ='Complete'    ) m ON 
    x.storageoid = m.storageoid
```

you need to limit your results from `XMLDocStorage` by IDs with your target value (`DMR`) only, any IDs with other `documentTypes` should be excluded.

Comment: note I changed the upper bound on collectedDTTime, I didn't want you to miss rows on that last day.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.AccountID AccountID, b.Visit_OID, b.DocumentType, 
    c.GenericName, c.DocumentStatus, b.CollectedDTime
FROM PatientVisit a
   JOIN XMLDocStorage b
      ON b.Visit_oid = a.Visit_OID
   JOIN MedList c
      ON c.storageoid = b.storageoid
 WHERE (c.GenericName LIKE '%warfarin%' OR 
     c.GenericName  LIKE '%enoxaparin%' OR 
     c.GenericName  LIKE '%rivaroxaban%' OR 
     c.GenericName  LIKE '%apixaban%' OR 
     c.GenericName  LIKE '%dabigatran etexilate%' OR 
     c.GenericName  LIKE '%edoxaban%')
   AND b.collectedDTime BETWEEN '20161001 00:00:00' 
                            AND '20161010  00:00:00'
   AND c.DocumentStatus ='Complete'
   And not exists (Select * From XMLDocStorage
                   Where Visit_oid = a.Visit_OID
                      and DocumentType != 'DNR')
```

Comment: Then every record in PatientVisit has an XMLDocStorage document that is not documentType 'DNR'.   Is that the criteria ? "with medications (warfarin, enoxaparin, rivaroxaban etc) with documenttype only of dmr"

Comment: The document type you mention that must be restricted to 'DNR' - is it the document type in the `XMLDocStorage` table?  cause that is not an attribute of the Medication.  Based on the statement " I need to display accountid with **medications** (warfarin, enoxaparin, rivaroxaban etc) with documenttype only of dmr", I would assume it should be an attribute of the `MedList` table.  Are you missing a join criteria between `MedList` and the `XMLDocStorage` tables ?

Comment: in the select clause, documentType is from table b, xmlDocStorage

Comment: If `documentType` is from table `xmlDocStorage`, what do you mean by *medications  ....  with documenttype only of dmr*?